# ASCII Encoding and decoding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have web page which posts the data and it is accepted as below...

```
NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody]  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Question 1:  is there any better way of doing this? my concern is about "encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding"

This essentially is an array. And the row values in this array contains ascii characters (such as %40) which originally was (@). the @ symbol got converted to %40 as I used NSASCIIStringEncoding as mentioned above.
Question 2: is there a way to decode it back to original character for the whole string at one go.

Comment: What "encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding" does is tell NSString to read the byte buffer it received as an ASCII byte string. If you're seeing %40 instead of @ in postData, it means that the %40 was already in [request HTTPBody], as three bytes. This representation is known as URL encoding (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding ), and is different from string encoding (see here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ).

Comment: Thanks for the info!! And you seem to be right that the value was already %40. Is there a way to get it back to the original character. consider the fact that there might be many such characters in the string and i want to decode the whole string back with the original characters.

Comment: See -[NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:] here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BCIECHFE

Comment: You are awesome, it is solved now. Thanks Mate!!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)